# Akka java threads choke on multiple JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, jvm, akka

I have an console application running on linux RH 6.5 machine.
trying to run load tests on that process.
When running 1 process on a very strong machine it is working properly and 
minimum stuck was from GC perspective. 
when trying to run 10 instances on that machine most of the process have very long GC pauses.

is it configurable changes need to be made in order to run the load test or evolves coding?
currently running on 5 threads Thread pool in Akka configuration and machine have 20 physical cpu with 128 GB ram.

Machine FS: http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=dd&subtype=ca&&htmlfid=897/ENUS112-144

Answer (score 1):

If the CPUs are oversubscribed you'll want to limit the thread pools used by akka and the # of GC threads.

If you you're seeing swapping then you'll have to limit each JVM to some fraction of the available memory so that the GC ergonomics don't unnecessarily inflate the heap size.